# Firestore app read from cache not working

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have setup my android firestore application similar to the [example quickstart application](https://github.com/firebase/friendlyeats-android/), in other words:

- `EntryActivity` displays documents in a collection
- When a document is clicked, pass the document ID to the `DetailsActivity`
- `DetailsActivity` uses it's own `FirebaseFirestore` reference to read that document with the ID
- Both the `EntryActivity` and `DetailsActivity` obtain their own `FirebaseFirestore` reference through `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()` in `onCreate`

However since the document being opened was previously read in the `EntryActivity`, I want the `DetailsActivity` to read it from the local cache **faster** than if it were read from the server.

In the `DetailsActivity`, when requesting the document from cache:

```
var time = System.currentTimeMillis()
firestore.collection(collectionPath)
    .document(docId)
    .get(Source.CACHE)
    .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time
        Log.v(TAG, "read took $time ms fromCache=${snapshot.metadata.isFromCache}")
    }
```

Results in:

```
read took 300-500 ms fromCache=true
```

Reading from server:

```
var time = System.currentTimeMillis()
firestore.collection(collectionPath)
    .document(docId)
    .get(Source.SERVER)
    .addOnSuccessListener { snapshot ->
        time = System.currentTimeMillis() - time
        Log.v(TAG, "read took $time ms fromCache=${snapshot.metadata.isFromCache}")
    }
```

Results in:

```
read took 300-500 ms fromCache=false
```

These were run multiple times to come up with an average time for each. There is no noticeable difference in speed when reading from cache.

To experiment I tried reading the document (after being already read) in the `EntryActivity` using the same `get(Source.CACHE)` method above, and it is faster like intended:

```
read took 30-80 ms fromCache=true
```

Why is reading from cache only faster in the first activity?

Comment: Are you sure that when you get `read took 300-500 ms fromCache=false` the document exists in the cache?

Comment: Yes, because it is read by the initial query, and can only be selected for reading again after being selected by the user. It works when reading from the same (`EntryActivity`). Just not when reading from the next activity `DetailsActivity`.

Comment: Are you sure about your observation? Here's what I have observed:
1. FirebaseFirestore instances are same in every activity!
2. If the fetch from Source.CACHE fails, the addOnSuccessListener callback is NOT fired
3. If the doc is already fetched from Server, Source.CACHE always returns true in snapshot.metadata.isFromCache You can find the sample app uploaded on github https://github.com/trivalent/SOQuestion

Comment: @RahulShukla You are correct, sorry. I have tested the behavior again and updated the question with what's happening. I am concerned over the time the request takes. I can re-read a document in the first activity and it is significantly faster when requesting from cache. However re-reading in the 2nd activity, there is no time difference in reading from cache vs server, even though the result says it's from cache.

Comment: @jefferson, for me it never crosses 30ms in the second activity. I read from the server in first activity, launch the second, reading from cache here. 
I am testing it on a simulator, FYI.
Doesn't make sense, but can you share your source?